# How to upgrade abp 5.14 to abp 6.0?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Abp new version 6.0 come out. My project version is 5.14.0, core 3.1, use Startup Templates, how to safe upgrade to abp v6.0?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Completed this upgrade myself - very straightforward.

**step 1:**

Change every project to use:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

**step 2:**

There's a small breaking change in this class's constructor. Code shown below I simply copied over the code from the new the new version to get it working:

```
  public class UserStore : AbpUserStore<Role, User>
    {
        public UserStore(
            IUnitOfWorkManager unitOfWorkManager,
            IRepository<User, long> userRepository,
            IRepository<Role> roleRepository,
            IRepository<UserRole, long> userRoleRepository,
            IRepository<UserLogin, long> userLoginRepository,
            IRepository<UserClaim, long> userClaimRepository,
            IRepository<UserPermissionSetting, long> userPermissionSettingRepository,
            IRepository<UserOrganizationUnit, long> userOrganizationUnitRepository,
            IRepository<OrganizationUnitRole, long> organizationUnitRoleRepository)
            : base(unitOfWorkManager,
                userRepository,
                roleRepository,
                userRoleRepository,
                userLoginRepository,
                userClaimRepository,
                userPermissionSettingRepository,
                userOrganizationUnitRepository,
                organizationUnitRoleRepository
            )
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The target framework and abp packages should be updated in each project:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

If you currently have the following you must change it to 6.0

```
<PackageReference Include="Abp.Castle.Log4Net" Version="5.13.0" />
```

Change by:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Abp.Castle.Log4Net" Version="6.0" />
```